# Another company has my domain in Japan

Tags: domains

I own a company and have the company name registered as a trademark.
I just discovered that someone has already bought my company name domain in Japan.

So say I own this company japancompany.com and I want to get the domain japancompany.jp
but someone else has already bought it.
Can I somehow get it back?

Comment: No you can't force the registrar to transfer it to you. Maybe if you have a registered company in Japan along with a good lawyer who's in Japan to make an attempt at getting it legally. Getting domains like that only works for famous world wide brands, Coca cola etc.

Comment: We have the trademark already in Japan so it is more can we then get the domain?

Comment: If you used an attorney in Japan to help get the trademark you should consult with them on what steps to take to get the domain. Whoever your contacts are in Japan if any shoot them an email and ask. Also give this a read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_trademark_law

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [Trademark and International Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark#International_law) on Wikipedia:

> It is important to note that although there are systems which facilitate the filing, registration or enforcement of trademark rights in more than one jurisdiction on a regional or global basis (e.g. the Madrid and CTM systems, see further below), it is currently not possible to file and obtain a single trademark registration which will automatically apply around the world.

You have the Madrid system or the Community Trade Mark system (of the European Union) or others for securing trademark registrations in different and more than one country. Doing it in more than one country is expensive - you probably know that and decided to not protect your trademark internationally. I would take a look if the company that registered it is in your jurisdiction. If not and you need it desperately, it might in fact be cheaper to buy it (often that's the business: I get mails from asian registrars twice a month that tell me they know someone will buy domain foo but they can register it for me and ...).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to purchase it from owner who registered it first.

Comment: Nice try, japancompany.jp owner